# Unable to Display PopupWindow message on Mobile

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I am creating a `PopupWindow` message on `onClick` event of a `ImageButton`, I can see the `PopupWindow` message on Emulator but can't see it on mobile, I have tried many mobiles from API 17 to 23.
I am not able to find the issue

```
@OnClick(R.id.infoRatingDetail)
public void ratingInfo(View view){
    TextView message;
    PopupWindow popup=new PopupWindow(getContext());
    View view_pop=inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_detail,null);
    message=(TextView)view_pop.findViewById(R.id.pop_up_textView);
    message.setText(R.string.rating_info);
    popup.setContentView(view_pop);
    popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popup.setFocusable(true);
    popup.showAsDropDown(view);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why but I had same problem & adding this two lines solved my problem.

```
popup.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popup.setHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popup.showAsDropDown(view);
popup.update();
```

Hope this will help you also.

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `getApplicationContext()` instead of `getContext()`?

Comment: i am using it in a fragment

Comment: so try `getActivity()` before getting context for your inflater?

Answer (score 0):

Try

> popup.setWindowLayoutMode(view.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,view.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: setWindowLayoutMode is deprecated

Comment: This is deprecated but instead you can use `setWidth()` and `setHeight()`